# Filling up a column using data from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Symbol    | Date    |    Version    |    Value
abc       | 20120101|    1          |    NULL
abc       | 20120101|    4          |    25
abc       | 20120101|    14         |    NULL
abc       | 20120101|    34         |    123
abc       | 20120101|    42         |    35
abc       | 20120101|    45         |    NULL
```

I need to update it so that it looks like this:

```
Symbol    | Date    |    Version    |    Value
abc       | 20120101|    1          |    NULL
abc       | 20120101|    4          |    25
abc       | 20120101|    14         |    25
abc       | 20120101|    34         |    123
abc       | 20120101|    42         |    35
abc       | 20120101|    45         |    35
```

That is, everytime there is a NULL in the Value column, I need to fill it up with the last non null Value according to the Version, for the given symbol and date.

I tried using an UPDATE along with a JOIN, but I don't know how to ensure that it uses a non NULL value from the most recent version, and not from any previous version.

This is what I tried:

```
UPDATE c1
SET c1.value = c2.value
FROM myTable updateC
JOIN myTable AS lookupC
ON 
    updateC.symbol = lookupC.symbol AND
    updateC.date = lookupC.date 
WHERE
    lookupC.firstRunId = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM      myTable c3 WHERE c3.version < updateC.version) AND 
updateC.value IS NULL and lookupC.value IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to specify what you mean by "the last" - you need some kind of ordering for this to work. If you have a newer system you should be able to make use of `LEAD` or `LAG`, otherwise `ROW_NUMBER` over a partition will be your best bet. What RDBMS are you using? Please post the code you have tried so far, including the JOINs you tried.

Comment: Does your DBMS support LAST_VALUE? Then it's a simple `LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY Version)`

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012 - it looks like I could use LAST_VALUE. The versions are ordered - by 'last' I mean the Maximum version less than this row's version. I updated the question to also include some more information (there are 2 more columns that this needs to match on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to phrase this is using a correlated subquery:

```
update myTable t
    set value = (select top 1 t2.value
                 from myTable t2
                 where t2.symbol = t.symbol and t2.date = t.date and
                       t2.version < t.version and t2.value is not null
                 order by t2.version desc
                )
    where t.value is null;
```

This would benefit (performance-wise) from an index on `mytable(symbol, date, version)`.

Note:  what you really want is the `IGNORE NULLS` keyword for `LAG()`.  However, SQL Server does not (yet) support this functionality.

EDIT:

There is another way to phrase this using `JOIN` and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when value is not null then version end) over
                 (partition by symbol, date order by version) as maxv
      from mytable t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = t.value
    from toupdate join
         mytable t
         on t.symbol = toupdate.symbol and t.date = toupdate.date and
            t.version = toupdate.maxv
    where toupdate.value is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have one question about the first solution, how would this work if the top 1 t2.value is NULL? I updated the first row of my test data to show this as an example. I need the data to stay NULL if it was NULL in preceeding versions. Once it gets a value, it always needs to have a value in following version.

Comment: @ame . . . If there is no preceding row with a value, then the result will be `NULL`.